# Blocked Facebook user highlighted in yellow

Tags: facebook

When I block a user on Facebook and it highlights in yellow, what does it mean? I have never seen this before and the highlighting seems very unusual. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you first block someone, it will direct you to a "manage blocking" page (https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=blocking) and append to the end of the url "`&blocked_uid=[user id]`". Under this specific url, Facebook highlights the user whose id is in the url. In this case, that means **the last person to be blocked is highlighted**.
If you remove "`&blocked_uid=[user id]`" from the url and hit enter, you will be redirected and no name will be highlighted. If you back up a page, you will return to the page with the id and the highlighted username.

<sup><sub>Source: https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10152989336137092&answer_id=10153723180997092&rdrhc</sub></sup>